# Difference between retrofit callbacks

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to know what is the difference between onFailure and when response is not successful in retrofit

```java
call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

        if (!response.isSuccessful()){
            *1
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
        *2
    }
});
```

When will be on *1 and *2 in the above callback

Comment: If you want the link: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html onResponse is called when you get a HTTP status code (can be anything from 1 to 9999 or whatever) and onFailure is when a "serious" error occurs, like getting disconnected halfway, server offline etc.

Comment: @Zun HTTP [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) are usually in the range from 100 until 511.

Comment: _usually_ yes you are correct.

Comment: isSuccessful is when you get a responseCode between 200 - 300 from the server.

Comment: *2 will be called when there's a connection error, maybe webserver is down..e.t.c Basically when your service was not reached...

Comment: @Zun you said "onResponse is called when you get a HTTP status code (can be anything from 1 to 9999 or whatever) and onFailure is when a "serious" error occurs, like getting disconnected halfway, server offline etc"  if the server go offline  and we get 503 error will onFailure be called ?

Comment: If the server is offline then how does it give back a 503 error? Also, did you read the message I sent you? Read https://httpstatuses.com/503. I already said when onFailure gets called. It does NOT get called when the server returns a 503 error. Instead, `onResponse` is called (because guess what, the received a response from the server) with `isSuccessful` on false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **onResponse**

void onResponse(Call call,
                Response response)
Invoked for a received HTTP response.
Note: An HTTP response may still indicate an application-level failure such as a 404 or 500. Call Response.isSuccessful() to determine if the response indicates success.

- **onFailure**

void onFailure(Call call,
               Throwable t)
Invoked when a network exception occurred talking to the server or when an unexpected exception occurred creating the request or processing the response.